# How to set buttons to disabled until another button is clicked first

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement that should force a user to click on a specific button first, before they are able to click any of the other button.
I am listing 4 buttons, but would like the Search button to be clicked first by disabling the other 3. Once the search is performed, then the rest of the buttons can become active. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
<ul class="slds-button-group-row">

                            <li class="slds-button-group-item">
                                <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--destructive slds-grow" value="Search" action="{!doAdvSearch}"  />
                            </li>
                            <li class="slds-button-group-item">
                                <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--destructive slds-grow" value="Clear Search" action="{!reset}"  />
                            </li>
                            <li class="slds-button-group-item">
                                <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--destructive slds-grow" value="Create Account" action="{!reset}"  />
                            </li>
                            <li class="slds-button-group-item">
                                <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--destructive slds-grow" value="Create Contact" action="{!reset}"  />
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just plain Visualforce, so you can do something like:

```
<apex:commandButton disabled="{!resetDisabled}" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--destructive slds-grow" value="Clear Search" action="{!reset}"  />
```

And in your controller:

```
public Boolean resetDisabled { get; set; }
...
// This is the constructor...
public MyVfController() {
  resetDisabled = true;
  ...
}
public void doAdvSearch() {
  resetDisabled = false;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I was hoping I can handle this purely within VF, but this certainly works. Thanks